# Delete from tables is not clearing oracle space

Tags: database, oracle

I've created a tablespace and user and I've 10 tables under this user, having LOB objects which is eating up the space but it required as part of the application. I've created a delete script which deletes the data before 30 days from these tables .But even after deleting the data from the tables, the space is not getting cleared .
When i had 200 days data , I had 5% free space .And now i've 30 days data , still 5% free space . 
Please advice , how I can cover up with this situation . It is critical .

Comment: Is the available space elastic?

Comment: Not sure. But if you want me to extend the space . That is the worst case. I want to know , how can i clear the space which is occupied because clearing the tables data is not working . Please note , i've to keep the data as it is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an extent is allocated to a table (or index, etc) it belongs to that table until you

1. drop the table
2. truncate the table

When you delete the data from the table -- the blocks will go onto the freelist for that table (assuming the amount of space on a block that was freed fell below the pctused). These blocks will be used for subsequent inserts and updates into this table.

As Tom suggests https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1336002638218 to reclaim the space you can:

1. create a new locally managed tablespace with autoextend datafiles (so the files will grow just as big as needed)
2. alter table T move tablespace that_new_one
3. drop tablespace that_old_one;

Comment: It was really helpful :) Thanks Evgeniy